# ReactJS: webpack: Failed to compile with spread syntax

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to show you my problem.

My env:

```
Node: 8.9.1
npm: 5.6.0
yarn: 1.3.2
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
...
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.2"
  },
```

webpack.config.js

```
...
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: ['react', 'env']
            }
          }
        },
...
```

**It always compile failed like this forcus on {...}**

> ERROR in ./src/flux/components/BaseComponent.js Module build failed:
>   SyntaxError: D:/APPs/src/flux/components/BaseComponent.js: Unexpected
>   token (36:29)
>
> ```
>  34 |     let {search} = this.state;
>   35 |     search.includeActive = !search.includeActive;
> > 36 |     this.setState({category : {...this.state.category, name : name}});
>
>      |
> ```

However, It work well without webpack.
Please, help me to solve this problem!
Thank you so much to all of you! :)

Comment: install `babel-preset-state-0` and add it to preset presets: `['react', 'env', 'stage-0]` to use spread syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use spread syntax, you need to configure you babel loader, You have a couple of option

**First:** Use plugin `"transform-object-rest-spread"`

Install it using

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

and use it

```
   options: {
       cacheDirectory: true,
       presets: ['react', 'env']
       plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
   }
```

**Second:** use `stage-0` preset, Install it using

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

and use it like

```
options: {
   cacheDirectory: true,
   presets: ['react', 'env', 'stage-0']
}
```

Check **[this babel-documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)**