# Javascript - React - return multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component I have the following method to keep the state and props in sync:

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        return nextProps.filterName === prevState.filterName ? '' : { filterName: nextProps.filterName };
    }
```

This is valid and working, but I want to also add a second line in the same method to update another state property:

```
   return nextProps.saveChecked === prevState.saveChecked ? false : { saveChecked: nextProps.saveChecked };
```

If I replace the existing return statement for filterName with this one for saveChecked, it works. I get an error when adding both "return" statements that it is invalid. Is there a valid way to rewrite this so both state properties can be updated?

Comment: can you please share what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a newState in a separate object and then return it at once;

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const newState = {}; 
    if(nextProps.filterName !== prevState.filterName) { 
        newState =  {...newState, filterName: nextProps.filterName };
    }
    if(nextProps.saveChecked !== prevState.saveChecked) {
        newState = {...newState, saveChecked: nextProps.saveChecked }
    }
    //check if the object is not empty
    if(!(Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object)) {
        return newState;
    }
    return null

 }
```

Comment: The property spread notation doesn't work in my project, and do I need to replace Object and obj with something? They aren't defined. Thanks!

Comment: try with replacing ...newState with Object.assign(newState)

Comment: You can set up spread syntax to work in your project, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474518/reactjs-webpack-failed-to-compile-with-spread-syntax/48474584#48474584. Otherwise you can write, `Object.assign({}, newState, {saveChecked: nextProps.saveChecked})`