# How to correctly handle non PrivateRoutes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this piece of code in my app.js and have configured a PrivateRoute which requires the user to login and only allows access if the cookie is set. However, I would like to restrict users trying to hit `/login` after they have successfully logged in. I used the reverse logic of the PrivateRoute and created LoginRoute which serves the purpose but would like to know if there is a better approach.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import cookies from 'cookies-js';

import Home from './homeComponent';
import Login from './loginComponent';
import Dashboard from './dashboardComponent';
import NoMatch from './noMatchComponent';

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
          <LoginRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};

const LoginRoute = ({ component: Component, rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    cookies.get('access-token')
      ? <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/dashboard',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
      : <Component {...props} />
  )} />
)

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    cookies.get('access-token')
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle Private Routes, one such way is to write a custom Login route as you have written which prevents user from visiting `/login`  if he/she is already loggedIn. The only correction that you need to make in your route is to use `rest syntax correctly`

```
const LoginRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    cookies.get('access-token')
      ? <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/dashboard',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
      : <Component {...props} />
  )} />
)
```

and PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    cookies.get('access-token')
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)
```

The other way to handle this would be an authentication HOC.

```
const RequireAuth = (Component) => { 

    return class App extends Component { 

        render() { 
           const { location } = this.props;
           if (cookies.get('access-token')) {
               if(location.pathname === '/login') {
                    return <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />
               }
               return <Component {...this.props} /> 
           }
           return <Redirect to="/login"/>
        }
    } 

} 

export { RequireAuth }
```

and you would use it like

```
const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={RequireAuth(Login)} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'll give the authentication HOC a try. It seems to be a much more cleaner solution. On another note, using `const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (` instead of `const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, rest }) => (` give me an error when compiling my app. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: the error would probably be solved using a plugin, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474518/reactjs-webpack-failed-to-compile-with-spread-syntax/48474584#48474584